# How to get the state of the keyboard in AHK script?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

In AHK, how to get the array of boolean values representing the state of every key on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Different keyboard layouts come with different keys. You have to know the names of the keys in order to check them and it has to be done key by key. 
You would basically use `GetKeyState("KeyName","P")`.

If you have an array of keys that you want to check you could loop ofer the key array, cehck every key and store the results in another array:

```
keysToCheck = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p"]
keyStates = {}
for i, key in keysToCheck
{
    keyState := GetKeyState("KeyName","P")
    keyStates.Insert(key,keyState)
}

; keyStates now contains all the key states

MsgBox % keyStates["q"]
MsgBox % keyStates["w"]
```

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

I did find an amazing AHK Script that can Monitor All your **Pressed keys** and **keyboard shortcuts combinations** and **Mouse clicks**, The Script is long but then you are able to get the state of **All** the keyboard movements.

if you look to the Codeline `GuiControl,     , HotkeyText, %HotkeyStr%` from the KeypressOSD.ahk script - then this `%HotkeyStr%` is the variable where you recieve the Value what you did pressed.

If you Change the Code a litte bit - and remove some Gui's codelines lines + write this `%HotkeyStr%` value
to the Windows Registry, you can then get everytime the key press value from the registry **with one codeline** and use it, then in any kind of ahk scripts.

You can Replace this and remove some GUI codelines.

```
RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER,software\GetKeypressValue,KeypressValue,%HotkeyStr%
```

Now you can use it in any ahk script with one codeline. (note - run it together with KeypressOSD.ahk script)

```
 RegRead, KeypressValue, HKEY_CURRENT_USER,software\GetKeypressValue,KeypressValue ; read KeypressValue
```

If you Look to this Youtube Video you can see what it can do.

[Detect Keypress Value From Windows Registry key.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap2YKZbEgnA)

[image]

note!! This program was created by Author RaptorX.
And It works on Windows 10 System.

[image: get keypress value autohotkey]

KeypressOSD.ahk

```
; KeypressOSD.ahk
; Open this Script in Wordpad and For Changelog look to the Bottom of the script. 
;This code works with a getkeyname from a Dllcall (See Bottom Script- by Lexikos)
;you can press the esc key to exit.

#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines, -1
ListLines, Off

; Settings
    global TransN                := 200      ; 0~255
    global ShowSingleKey         := True
    global ShowMouseButton       := True
    global ShowSingleModifierKey := True
    global ShowModifierKeyCount  := true
    global ShowStickyModKeyCount := false
    global DisplayTime           := 2000     ; In milliseconds
    global GuiPosition           := "Bottom" ; Top or Bottom
    global FontSize              := 50
    global GuiHeight             := 115

CreateGUI()
CreateHotkey()
return

OnKeyPressed:
    try {
        key := GetKeyStr()
        ShowHotkey(key)
        SetTimer, HideGUI, % -1 * DisplayTime
    }
return

OnKeyUp:
return

_OnKeyUp:
    tickcount_start := A_TickCount
return


CreateGUI() {
    global

    Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +Owner +LastFound +E0x20
    Gui, Margin, 0, 0
    Gui, Color, Black
    Gui, Font, cWhite s%FontSize% bold, Arial
    Gui, Add, Text, vHotkeyText Center y20

    WinSet, Transparent, %TransN%
}

CreateHotkey() {
    Loop, 95
    {
        k := Chr(A_Index + 31)
        k := (k = " ") ? "Space" : k

        Hotkey, % "~*" k, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" k " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Loop, 24 ; F1-F24
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*F" A_Index, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*F" A_Index " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Loop, 10 ; Numpad0 - Numpad9
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*Numpad" A_Index - 1, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*Numpad" A_Index - 1 " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    Otherkeys := "WheelDown|WheelUp|WheelLeft|WheelRight|XButton1|XButton2|Browser_Forward|Browser_Back|Browser_Refresh|Browser_Stop|Browser_Search|Browser_Favorites|Browser_Home|Volume_Mute|Volume_Down|Volume_Up|Media_Next|Media_Prev|Media_Stop|Media_Play_Pause|Launch_Mail|Launch_Media|Launch_App1|Launch_App2|Help|Sleep|PrintScreen|CtrlBreak|Break|AppsKey|NumpadDot|NumpadDiv|NumpadMult|NumpadAdd|NumpadSub|NumpadEnter|Tab|Enter|Esc|BackSpace"
               . "|Del|Insert|Home|End|PgUp|PgDn|Up|Down|Left|Right|ScrollLock|CapsLock|NumLock|Pause|sc145|sc146|sc046|sc123"
    Loop, parse, Otherkeys, |
    {
        Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField " Up", _OnKeyUp
    }

    If ShowMouseButton {
        Loop, Parse, % "LButton|MButton|RButton", |
            Hotkey, % "~*" A_LoopField, OnKeyPressed
    }

    for i, mod in ["Ctrl", "Shift", "Alt"] {
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod, OnKeyPressed
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod " Up", OnKeyUp
    }
    for i, mod in ["LWin", "RWin"]
        Hotkey, % "~*" mod, OnKeyPressed
}

ShowHotkey(HotkeyStr) {
    WinGetPos, ActWin_X, ActWin_Y, ActWin_W, ActWin_H, A
    if !ActWin_W
        throw

    text_w := (ActWin_W > A_ScreenWidth) ? A_ScreenWidth : ActWin_W
    GuiControl,     , HotkeyText, %HotkeyStr%
    GuiControl, Move, HotkeyText, w%text_w% Center

    if (GuiPosition = "Top")
        gui_y := ActWin_Y
    else
        gui_y := (ActWin_Y+ActWin_H) - 115 - 50

    Gui, Show, NoActivate x%ActWin_X% y%gui_y% h%GuiHeight% w%text_w%
}

GetKeyStr() {
    static modifiers := ["Ctrl", "Shift", "Alt", "LWin", "RWin"]
    static repeatCount := 1

    for i, mod in modifiers {
        if GetKeyState(mod)
            prefix .= mod " + "
    }

    if (!prefix && !ShowSingleKey)
        throw

    key := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 3)

    if (key ~= "i)^(Ctrl|Shift|Alt|LWin|RWin)$") {
        if !ShowSingleModifierKey {
            throw
        }
        key := ""
        prefix := RTrim(prefix, "+ ")

        if ShowModifierKeyCount {
            if !InStr(prefix, "+") && IsDoubleClickEx() {
                if (A_ThisHotKey != A_PriorHotKey) || ShowStickyModKeyCount {
                    if (++repeatCount > 1) {
                        prefix .= " ( * " repeatCount " )"
                    }
                } else {
                    repeatCount := 0
                }
            } else {
                repeatCount := 1
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( StrLen(key) = 1 ) {
            key := GetKeyChar(key, "A")
        } else if ( SubStr(key, 1, 2) = "sc" ) {
            key := SpecialSC(key)
        } else if (key = "LButton") && IsDoubleClick() {
            key := "Double-Click"
        }
        _key := (key = "Double-Click") ? "LButton" : key

        static pre_prefix, pre_key, keyCount := 1
        global tickcount_start
        if (prefix && pre_prefix) && (A_TickCount-tickcount_start < 300) {
            if (prefix != pre_prefix) {
                result := pre_prefix pre_key ", " prefix key
            } else {
                keyCount := (key=pre_key) ? (keyCount+1) : 1
                key := (keyCount>2) ? (key " (" keyCount ")") : (pre_key ", " key)
            }
        } else {
            keyCount := 1
        }

        pre_prefix := prefix
        pre_key := _key

        repeatCount := 1
    }
    return result ? result : prefix . key
}

SpecialSC(sc) {
    static k := {sc046: "ScrollLock", sc145: "NumLock", sc146: "Pause", sc123: "Genius LuxeMate Scroll"}
    return k[sc]
}

; by Lexikos - https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/110808-getkeyname-for-other-languages/#entry682236
GetKeyChar(Key, WinTitle:=0) {
    thread := WinTitle=0 ? 0
        : DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "ptr", WinExist(WinTitle), "ptr", 0)
    hkl := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "uint", thread, "ptr")
    vk := GetKeyVK(Key), sc := GetKeySC(Key)
    VarSetCapacity(state, 256, 0)
    VarSetCapacity(char, 4, 0)
    n := DllCall("ToUnicodeEx", "uint", vk, "uint", sc
        , "ptr", &state, "ptr", &char, "int", 2, "uint", 0, "ptr", hkl)
    return StrGet(&char, n, "utf-16")
}

IsDoubleClick(MSec = 300) {
    Return (A_ThisHotKey = A_PriorHotKey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < MSec)
}

IsDoubleClickEx(MSec = 300) {
    preHotkey := RegExReplace(A_PriorHotkey, "i) Up$")
    Return (A_ThisHotKey = preHotkey) && (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < MSec)
}

HideGUI() {
    Gui, Hide
}

esc::exitapp    
;---------------------------------------------
; ChangeLog : v2.22 (2017-02-25) - Now pressing the same combination keys continuously more than 2 times,
;                                  for example press Ctrl+V 3 times, will displayed as "Ctrl + v (3)"
;             v2.21 (2017-02-24) - Fixed LWin/RWin not poping up start menu
;             v2.20 (2017-02-24) - Added displaying continuous-pressed combination keys.
;                                  e.g.: With CTRL key held down, pressing K and U continuously will shown as "Ctrl + k, u"
;             v2.10 (2017-01-22) - Added ShowStickyModKeyCount option
;             v2.09 (2017-01-22) - Added ShowModifierKeyCount option
;             v2.08 (2017-01-19) - Fixed a bug
;             v2.07 (2017-01-19) - Added ShowSingleModifierKey option (default is True)
;             v2.06 (2016-11-23) - Added more keys. Thanks to SashaChernykh.
;             v2.05 (2016-10-01) - Fixed not detecting "Ctrl + ScrollLock/NumLock/Pause". Thanks to lexikos.
;             v2.04 (2016-10-01) - Added NumpadDot and AppsKey
;             v2.03 (2016-09-17) - Added displaying "Double-Click" of the left mouse button.
;             v2.02 (2016-09-16) - Added displaying mouse button, and 3 settings (ShowMouseButton, FontSize, GuiHeight)
;             v2.01 (2016-09-11) - Display non english keyboard layout characters when combine with modifer keys.
;             v2.00 (2016-09-01) - Removed the "Fade out" effect because of its buggy.
;                                - Added support for non english keyboard layout.
;                                - Added GuiPosition setting.
;             v1.00 (2013-10-11) - First release.
;--------------------------------------------
```